# What should be the expected way to unselect a dropdown

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

I have a dropdown which shows `select One` before any of the options are selected.Once the user has selected one of the options .what is the accepted way to  unselect that option and go back to the first stage where in no option was selected.

One way is to give `Select One` as an option in the pull down and let user select it if he wants to unselect one option.Is this the accepted way?

Comment: Don't know if it is in the html spec but isn't ctrl+click the usual way to unselect a select option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case "none" is also an option, just like any other option in the dropdown. Why don't just name it **"None"**!?

It's a selectbox/dropdown, you don't need to add "Select one" or "Make a choice" to make that clear. Place a label and make it helpful: "Which fruit do you like?"

If the dropdown is a mandatory field in the form, you can make one option default or use "Not selected yet" instead of just "none". The label or a (*) should make clear the field is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

If you 'disable' the first option and make it 'selected' then you can use it as an initial label. This way you can separate the action you want people to do from the 'None' option.

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option>Option A</option>
  <option>Option B</option>
  <option>None</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: But this pattern doesn't work for optional fields ...

Comment: A dropdown can't really be optional. You can default to a value that conveys the same as a null value. For example 'no dietary requirements' in food options.